# Marking message as completed in secondary region of RAGRS Azure Storage Queue if primary regions is down

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-queues

I am using RAGRS Azure Storage Queue. If the primary region has an outage and the consumer is reading from secondary region of the queue, can it mark the message as completed on that region as it doesn't support write functionality?

Answer (score 0):

First, secondary region is read only. You can't write to it. Because you can't write to it, you can only `PEEK` messages from a queue if you're directly reading from a secondary location which essentially prevents you from making any modifications to that message (like deleting the message to mark as complete).

Also, if the primary region has an outage (and this outage is declared by Microsoft), then your secondary region automatically becomes primary region (you don't have to do anything special for that). In that case, you will perform operations same as you were doing with the primary region before the outage.

Comment: i think MS SLA is 24 hours for failover? so its not like it will happen instantaneously?

Comment: I'm not sure about the 24 hour SLA (would appreciate if you share a link for that).

Comment: I cant seem to find the link, but [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-redundancy-grs?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fqueues%2ftoc.json#what-is-the-rpo-and-rto-with-grs) suggest MS gives no eta on failover.

Comment: @GauravMantri Then in case an outage happens but has not yet been detected / declared by Azure team what are the capabilities of Azure Storage Queue? If I can only PEEK the message and not complete and remove it, will my consumer keep on receiving the message?

Comment: `If I can only PEEK the message and not complete and remove it, will my consumer keep on receiving the message?` - That is correct. If you're reading directly from the secondary location, you can only perform read operations. Write and delete operations are not supported. Attempts to do so will result in an error from storage side.